# Create default folder in user home using property files in java

Tags: java, properties

How do I create a default folder in user.home using property files in java.
My intention here is to give my application a default folder in c:/users/abcd/default_folder where all app related files can be stored. Till now I was doing this in java code which checks for specific folder in user.home and creates it if doesnt exist. But to improve the efficiency, I want to do this through property files while application loads.

Need suggestions!

Comment: What do you mean "through property files"?  Do you mean you want to do something like `%user.dir%/%app.name%/config.properties`, which `%..%` indicates variables that need to be substituted?

Comment: I mean, I saw log4j.properties which actually creates folders to store logs of app. So similarly, I'm hoping we'll have some mechanism to create folders using config.properties or similar other property files.

Comment: I'm afraid not.  You'd still have to do this manually some how.  So while you could specify directory paths in a properties file, you'd still to manually create them...

Comment: Alright! Any snippet? please..

Comment: Well, you're already doing it...

Answer (score 0):

A basic example might look something like...

```
Properties p = new Properties();
Reader reader = null;

try {
    reader = new FileReader(new File("config.properties"));
    p.load(reader);

    for (Object key : p.keySet()) {
        String value = p.get(key).toString();
        // if is file reference...
        File file = new File(value);
        File path = file.getParentFile();
        if (path.exists() || path.mkdir()) {
            // Create/read file...
        } else {
            System.err.println("Failed to make/find directory for " + path);
        }
    }

} catch (IOException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

You will need to provide meaning to each to determine what actions you should take, for example, if they are prefixed with `file.` you might consider it some kind of `File`, so you will need to get the parent path.